# Αppropriate enslembe for describing systems interacting through a diaphragm

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics

Lets say we have two systems in equilibrium in a cubical box of side L.The energy in the left half of the box is $\epsilon_L=\frac{p^2}{2m}+V_0$ and on the right $\epsilon_R=\frac{p^2}{2m}$.We know that the total number of particles is N.We will describe each individual system in the Grand Canonical ensemble.The partition functions are:
$$Q_L=exp(e^{\beta \mu}e^{-\beta V_0}\frac{V}{\lambda^3_T})$$
and
$$Q_R=exp(e^{\beta \mu}\frac{V}{\lambda^3_T})$$
From the constant number of total particles we can calculate the chemical potential to be $\mu =k_\beta T ln(\lambda^3_T\frac{N}{V}\frac{1}{e^{-\beta V_0}+1})$.Now we instert a diaphragm that can move freely and also set the potential on the left side to zero.The question is where will this diaphragm balance out.Thats what i thought about it:

**1.** If the diaphragm was stationary in the middle we could just differentiate the grand canonical potential by volume $P=-\frac{\partial J}{\partial V}$ whilst not changing the chemical potential.

**2.** For the moving diaphragm we can describe each system again in the canonical ensemble but with particle number $<N>_L$ and $<N>_R$ that we calculated earlier.And from there find the force.

I dont understand which description to use in each situation i described.Thanks in advance.

**Edit:** The problem I've been having is that if I describe the systems in the grand canonical ensemble the force on the diaphragm is independent of its position. 
 Also for the canonical description i dont have the excact numbers of particles in each region.